# Trying to find a particular synth/keyboard from this song

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to find the exact keyboard/synth that has been used to make the single key sound/chord(I would also love to what key/chord it is) at 0:02 and onwards whenever the bass guitar stops playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll stick my neck out & say it's a [Fender Rhodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodes_piano) - though half the time I'm wrong & it's a [Wurlitzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wurlitzer_electric_piano) ;-)

Both were 'real' instruments, electric pianos which generated sound by using a piano keyboard & mechanical levers & hammers similar to a real piano, but instead of strings, had metal bars or tines which were struck by the hammers.
The sound was then picked up by an electro-magnetic pickup similar to that on an electric guitar.

Characteristically, the Rhodes is brighter & more bell-like, the Wurly is a simpler sound with less overtones - but people got quite creative with modifications to them over the years, harder or softer hammers, effects pedals, different amps, so on occasion it's difficult to tell which is which.

Original instruments fetch good prices these days, but synthesised & sampled versions are widely available as software plugins, & are often far more sonically flexible that the original instruments.

My personal favourite is Applied Acoustics [Lounge Lizard](https://www.applied-acoustics.com/lounge-lizard-ep-4/) which uses both these pianos as base models, but with the flexibility to exchange components from each, giving more sound choices than you could ever get from any original piano.

Toontrack are also usually very good, though I don't own this particular one, their [EZkeys Classic Electrics](https://www.toontrack.com/product/ezkeys-classic-electrics/) would be worth a listen

A couple of famous examples…

### Fender Rhodes -

The Doors, Riders on the Storm -

Bee Gees, How Deep is your Love -

### Wurlitzer -

Supertramp, Dreamer

Queen, You're my best Friend -

Comment: Thank you for confirming this for me. I do have Lounge LIzard, but I don't know what preset gives it that mellow sound that I hear on Herbie Hancock and other Jazz/Funk acts. I did manage to find the preset that gives it the organ sound from the Doors though. I guess this is a topic meant for another question. But nevertheless, excellent answer

Comment: I also would like to know if that was a key or a chord that caused that 'super full' and mellow sound