# Trying to find a particular sound from a synthesizer from this song

Tags: sound, sound-libraries, keyboard

*I hope this isn't marked as a duplicate question because there is [another question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/35585/trying-to-find-a-particular-synth-keyboard-from-this-song) very similar to this but the song is different.*

I have struggle for many weeks to find the exact sound from the following song:

The keyboard seems to be using a CP-88 Yamaha keyboard. I am using a KORG Kross 2 66-Key keyboard.

The keyboardist plays using that sound (Sounds like a Synth Lead) in all the verses in that song. I have tried all the Synth Leads on my keyboard and I could not find any.

Are there any particular sounds that sound similar which I can use in my keyboard? Preferably free and something that I can download onto my keyboard?